# Date Convertion From Csv to Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need to convert the Received_Date  type of the csv when i am inserting date in to the Mysql database using php.in csv date type is in 25-Feb-2016 .but what i wants to happen is when its inserting to the database it needs to be in 2016-02-25 format.

Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            echo "<div class='block-content block-content-full bg-danger text-white-op'>";
            $deleterecords = "UPDATE TABLE data"; //empty the table of its current records
            mysql_query($deleterecords);

            $product = $_POST['product'];
            $courier = $_POST['courier'];
            $billmonth = $_POST['billmonth'];
            $billyear = $_POST['billyear'];
            $billrun = $_POST['billrun'];
            $dispatchtype = $_POST['dispatchtype'];


            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
                //echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
                echo "<p>Displaying contents:</p>";
                echo "<p>Product - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$product. " </strong> Service Provider - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$courier. "</strong> Bill Month - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billmonth. " </strong> Bill Year - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billyear. "</strong> Bill Run- <strong style='color: #ffc128'>" .$billrun. " </strong> Dispatch Type - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$dispatchtype."</strong></p><br/>";
                echo "<span style='color:#feffa4'>";
                readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
                echo "</span>";
            }

            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                /*$linecount = count(file('filename.csv'));*/


                if (($product==$data[0]) && ($courier==$data[1]) && ($billmonth==$data[6]) && ($billyear==$data[7]) && ($billrun==$data[8]) && ($dispatchtype==$data[9])) {

                    $import = "INSERT into data(Product,Courier,Received_Date,Acc_No,Received_By,Delivered_Date,Month,Year,Bill_Run,Dispatch_Type,Status,Bounce_Code) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";

                } else {

                    echo " <br/> <br/>Data Error.<br/>";
                    echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <br/> <br/>";
                }

                mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
            }

        fclose($handle);

        echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
        print "Import done ";/*$linecount*/
        echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-home'></i> Home</a>  <br/> <br/>";

        //view upload form

        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: you can use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($yourdate));`

Comment: or better use `DateTime` object

Comment: @budirec can u tell me in which line i can use that code?

Comment: use that for every date that you want to convert. I believe it's at your while  loop, add this first `$data[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[2]));`

Comment: @budirec Thank you very much it works.do me a little favor can u see i have commented one line right under the while loop. iam using that to the count the lines updated by csv.but it shows every time 1.   "import done 1".

Comment: change the `$linecount` in while loop to `$linecount++;`

Comment: You appear to be inserting data one line at a time. Is that right? (Ouch)

Comment: @budirec Thank you very Much it works